#  'fi' or 'fl' result in big "S"-like symbol

Tags: fonts, xetex, lyx, ligatures

I use LyX with XeTeX, and the output font is DejaVu Sans. When I write in the input text 'fi' or 'fl', the output text displays a strange big "S"-like symbol. I don't know why is that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to give more informations. A picture of your strange "S", a minimal example, log-file ... Did you try the font and the input in another application?

Comment: show the font setting in your document preamble

Comment: If you want to disable all ligatures, try `\setmainfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{DejaVu Sans}`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer - it works in vim

Comment: @Herbert I have `\usepackage{fontspec}`, `\usepackage{xltxtra}`, `usepackage{xunicode}`. I used `setmainfont` in the document (by pressing ctrl+L and {\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans})

Comment: @Ma Ming Thanks a lot, it works now, I guess it was this thing with 'Ligatures'! That's a great advice!

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of the DejaVu Fonts that has a bug? Try installing the newest one. Ligatures (i.e combining `ff` and similar combinations into a single symbol like in Herbert's example) *should* work (its one of the main selling points of TeX after all).

Comment: @Caramdir Ligatures work, the problem was that I didn't know how to dismiss them. I didn't want to combine multiple `ff`.

Answer (score 1):

if I put this

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
```

into Documents->Setting->Preamble, I'll get a document with correct ligatures, when viewing the pdf

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me, I had to follow Ma Ming's advice and switch off the Ligatures. Do you know whether there's a setting (I couldn't find) to switch them off by default?